# Phonegap how to update html js android application without a store

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I was thinking about how to implement an update system for my Phonegap app, and at least as far as Javascript is concerned the easiest way I could think of was to store the apk file in server, check for updates via version number, and then just download the apk file and make user install it.

How can I do that or ıs there any easiest way to do that ? Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: why dont you post it to android google play and you can update the version whenever you update your application. and use GCM to send the users messages or notifications to let them know whats coming or any updates are coming !.

Comment: Our customers don't wanna use app store.@StyleMe

Comment: your customers ? hmm seems like a private company or something. well in this case you upload it to your server and notify the "Customers" to update the application.